# When sending command to serial port it doesnt work

Tags: c#

I'm using a Fax-Modem to get Telephone number in a string.I'm trying to send a command in a serial port. I'm using this code below:

```
private static string PhoneNumber;
private SerialPort mySerialPort;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

mySerialPort.Open();

mySerialPort.WriteLine("at#cid=1");//It doesnt recognise this line



mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);     
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

       messageBox.Show(indata);
    }
```

I dont take any error, but the problem is that the command which i type it doesnt work. Normally if it will work it will get me the telephone number, now it doesnt show anything.

If i will type this command in hyperterminal it works fine! So i guess something is wrong with my code.

Comment: is the serial port correct? do you need to add error handling? is the device plugged in properly? do you have the right baud rate, parity, stop bits, etc?

Comment: Attach to `DataReceived` event before sending any command

Comment: you may need to add `\n` to the end of your command, most serial interfaces use a newline to tell when a command is finished

Comment: @KeithM see the *WriteLine* in question

Comment: with \n in the end of my command it didnt work. I thing the problem is something like that. Should i use any code like hittinh enter key after my command?

Comment: I used \r after my command and it worked perfectly.thank you for advices!

Comment: So post  an answer to your own question. It may help someone in future.

Answer (score 2):

I used \r after my command and it worked perfectly.thank you for advices!

Here is my code:

```
    mySerialPort.WriteLine("at#cid=1\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wire the `DataReceived` event **before** opening the port and sending any command.

Comment: You may want to set a `ReadTimeOut` like this-


`mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;`